# BlueZ - accepted connection from 00:00:00:00:00:00

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

My c-program should listen for incoming Bluetooth connections. I read the example at http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html, so I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth.h>
#include <rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    // allocate socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    printf("socket: %d \n", s);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    printf("put socket into listening mode \n");
    listen(s, 1);

    // accept one connection
    printf("accept one connection \n");
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    // read data from the client
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }

    printf("close connection");
    // close connection
    close(client);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

But instead of waiting for incoming connection requests, it´s connecting to the address 00:00:00:00:00:00 immediately ([see Linux terminal output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lztuf.png)). So my program starts, setting the socket in listening mode, accepting connection from 00:00... and closing the connection again. I don´t know what the 00:00... adress is standing for but its definitely not the address of the computer I want to connect to.

Btw, the Bluetooth adapter is working fine, scanning for devices works and it´s also possible to connect to other computers with default Bluetooth commands in the Terminal. But I need to do this in a c-program to analyze the incoming messages.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The example code always binds to rfcomm channel 1. But that channel may already be in use on your machine. To diagnose the problem further I suggest you check the return values of all your function calls. In particular, `bind`, `listen` and `accept`. If any of those fail then print the `errno` or call `perror` to see what the specific error is.

Comment: @kaylum Return values of these function calls are all -1, meaning there is an error. I changed the value of `loc_addr.rc_channel` to try other channels. Now the return values are 0 and it´s listening for a connection. But when connecting to the device from another device, it is not shown by the c-program, it is still waiting for a connection at the `accept`-function.

Comment: Can't help you with the information you have provided. Because I don't know how you are doing "connecting to the device from another device". So it's impossible to say which end has the problem.

Comment: I start the program and wait until "accept one connection" is outprinted. Afterwards I take another device (e.g. a Smartphone) and connect to the device, which is running the c-program, via Bluetooth. On my Smartphone i can see that both devices are connected. But the c-program doesn´t outprint "accepted connection from Smartphone_BTAddress", it´s still waiting for a connection request.

Comment: " I take another device (e.g. a Smartphone) and connect to the device". That doesn't help. There are many ways to "connect" via bluetooth. If the connection is not set up properly then the expected behaviour will not occur. For example the smartphone might be connected to a different rfcomm channel. Or even to a different Bluetooth profile altogether. Without knowing exactly how that connection is made it is impossible to know what the problem is.

Comment: I see, I will now set up a SDP Service, maybe this works better. Thx for your help.